# Bucketing years in R

Tags: r, grouping

I have data in this format upto the year 2013. (approximate 125 years of data)

```
    Season  HomeGoals   AwayGoals   HomeWins    AwayWins    Draws
    1888    350            236        78          32          22
    1889    395            216        74          35          23
    1890    357            197        82          34          16
```

I wanted to group the years in buckets of 10 years, where the different columns like HomeGoals and others are added together in the bucket.
I tried the cut function which is available in R,but it didnt work.

```
demoCut <- cut(df_season$Season,breaks = 10)
```

The demoCut variable shows odd values like (1.89e + 0.5).

How do I bucket these years?

Answer (score 0):

Are your years numeric?

```
years <- as.numeric(c("1888", "1889", "1890", "1900"))

cut <- cut(years, breaks = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that your years were stored in the dataframe column labeled `year`. Your dataframe is `df`, and you want a new column `year_grouping` containing the "bucket" that your years fall in.

In this example, suppose that your years ranged from 2000 -> 2016, and you wanted to group them every 4 years. The following code would accomplish this:

```
df$year_grouping <- cut(df$year, c(2000:2016, 4))
```